# How to center align img wrapped in SPAN tag?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center align an image that is wrapped in a `<span>`, but I am having trouble doing so. I have uploaded my CSS and HTML to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7nHhu/1/

I am trying to get the image to center align itself with the content in a "block" style (ie. all text above and below it, not wrapped to the left or right)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
.imgframe {
border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
display: inline-block;
margin: 8px;
}
.imgframe img {
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
margin: 0;
background: #F6F6F6;
padding: 8px;
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #CCCCCC;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #CCCCCC;
}

<span class="imgframe centerimg"><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/31368e9.jpg" /></span>​
```

Comment: So why not use `display: block` on the `.imgframe` element? Or, better yet, use a `div`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make image wrapper block level element and `text-align:center;` it.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7nHhu/2/)

or wrap it in another element if needed;

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7nHhu/8/)

Answer (score 7):

I think it's more appropriate to use text-align for centering text rather than images. You could center an image by setting  left and right margin auto.

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 10px; //margin-top doesn't work
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7nHhu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In .imgframe, add width: 100%;

Comment: ...but I don't want the frame taking up the entire width of the page, only 8px outside the edge of the image.

Comment: Then surround it with a div and make the width 100% on the div.  The container must know how wide the page is in order to center it.

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements, to keep the `.imgframe` element in-line, to avoid it taking up the full width of the enclosing element, and working without adding wrapping elements to your mark-up, the following works:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

body p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7nHhu/13/).

This would, probably, be less intrusive if you had the elements from your Fiddle wrapped in a specific, target-able, element; rather than the `body`, as the method, above, requires you to reset the `text-align` for all elements contained within the `body`. So, personally, I'd use:

```
<div id="contentWrapper">
    <p>...</p>
    <span class="imgframe">
        <img src="..." />
    </span>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

And:

```
#contentWrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

#contentWrapper p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Just in order to minimise the amount of work required to tidy up afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

```
span {position: absolute; top:0; left: 0; width: 100%; text-align: center;}
img {width:yourimagewidth; heigth: width:yourimageheigth}
```